# Why does `nice` with a negative argument (e.g. `nice -15`) increment niceness?

Tags: gnu, options, nice

My `nice` is from GNU coreutils 9.1. I observed that `nice -15` is equivalent to `nice -n 15`:

```
     nice               # prints 0 for me, the base niceness is 0
     nice -n  15 nice   # prints 15, this is expected
sudo nice -n -15 nice   # prints -15, this is expected
     nice    -15 nice   # prints 15
```

`-15` is a negative number. Why does it increment the niceness in the last example above? The manual (e.g. in Debian 12) does not explain this.

Comment: "Because it's specified that way" (the nice(2) manual page says. "*A higher nice value means a low priority.)*". Or is your question "*Why was it specified that way?*"?

Comment: You are answering what you _think_ he asked, not what he actually asked...

Answer (score 29):

The [portable syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/nice.html) requires `-n` if you want to specify an increment. When in doubt, use `nice -n`.

In `nice -15` the argument is not really a negative number. It is a dash concatenated with a *positive* number. The leading dash indicates it is an option. Compare this e.g. to `kill -15` which is equivalent to `kill -s 15`. Similarly `nice -15` is equivalent to `nice -n 15`.

`kill -15` is not as confusing as `nice -15`, because you don't expect signal numbers to be negative. In the case of `nice` you were confused because an adjustment to niceness may be negative and <dash><digit(s)> surely looks like a non-positive number. It's easy to interpret `-15` as "minus fifteen" in cases where negative numbers make sense.

Note the number after the dash may be with an explicit sign:

```
     nice -+15 nice   # prints 15
sudo nice --15 nice   # prints -15
```

Unfortunately `--15` looks kinda like a long option (compare: `--help`) with a positive number, this may add to the confusion. It is another reason to prefer `nice -n`.

Comment: You don't expect signal numbers to be negative but negative pids are interpreted as pgids, so there is confusion here as well. Is `kill -15 16` the same as `kill -s TERM -- -15 16` (kill pgid 15 and pid 16 with SIGTERM) or is it `kill -s 15 16` (kill pid 16 with signal 15)

Comment: This is a good answer in that it explains the reality of the situation; but personally I would have stopped after the first two paragraphs. To my mind, neither `nice` nor `kill` make a whole lot of sense. I think the whole idea of passing positive numbers with leading dashes is highly suspect, and should be entirely re-thought.

Comment: Something similar happens with `head` and `tail`: `head -5` and `tail -5` mean `head -n 5` and `tail -n 5`, respectively.

Comment: Another victim of using the same ASCII symbol for hyphen and minus.

Comment: @PaulDraper: Would you prefer it if `nice ‐15` and `nice −15` were distinct commands that behaved completely differently?

Comment: @ruakh They do behave differently: the latter looks for a file `−15` (and emits an error for me, since I don't have such a file).

Comment: @Ruslan: Er, right. (In fact, that's also what the former does.) But I hope you do understand my point?

Comment: @ruakh, yeah I'd prefer ASCII not have a "hyphen-minus" symbol, but rather have both.